# getting text from notepad by control's hwnd

Tags: python

```
import win32gui
import time

while True:
    window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    title = win32gui.GetWindowText(window)
    print(window)


    if 'Notepad' in title:
        control = win32gui.FindWindowEx(window, 0, 'Edit', None)
        controldlgid = win32gui.GetDlgCtrlID(control)
        print(controldlgid)
        try:
            mytext = win32gui.GetDlgItemText(window, controldlgid)
            print(mytext)
        except:
            print('an error occured')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'd like to use win32gui.GetDlgItemText to get what is wrote on the activated notepad window
and here's my code.

it's not working.:(

for detail, there's not error occured, but the variable named mytext is empty.

what did I do wrong?